# how to block write of slave pty

Tags: linux, block, blocking, pty

Assume we have a code

```
pid_t pid = forkpty(&fd, &name, NULL, NULL);
if (pid < 0) return;
if (pid == 0) {
   // child process
} else {
   // parent process to handle pty master
}
```

How to block the `write` in subprocess (pty slave) until parent process (pty master) read it.

Comment: Why do you think you need to? If there's no reader yet, data will be buffered by the pty — it won't be lost.

Comment: I know it's not going to be lost. But I want to hang child process at its first write for some purpose.

Comment: I didn't find any option to set buffer size.

Comment: The pty buffer is a fixed size, and the child process will already be blocked if it tries to write to the pty while the buffer is full. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to check every syscall that qemu user mode emulated before passing it to real systems. I need to block qemu. (not when the buffer is full, but on every write)

Comment: That sounds more like a job for `ptrace()` to me. If you wait until the child process's first write to the PTY, you'll miss every system call before that, which may be quite a few.

Comment: I know ptrace, but the system's kernel is compiled to disable ptrace for some reasons, while I don't have permisions to change the kernel.

Comment: The original purpose is to check syscalls of a program, but ptrace is disabled. One way is to use qemu to simulate that program in user mode and trying to block qemu before examing every syscall.